# Difference between BuiltList and List.unmodifiable

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm trying to create an immutable list of immutable items.
I've seen and tried BuiltList from built_collection, now I've seen List.unmodifiable.

Are they equivalent i.e. using them I come up to the same result, which is having an unmodifiable list of items?

As far as I can tell, BuiltList returns an Iterable, while List.unmodifiable returns a list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

BuiltList supports the builder pattern used everywhere in `built_value` which makes it easy to create modified copies and be used together with generated `built_value` classes.
If you don't need this, just stick with `List.unmodifiable`

Comment: Equality might be another difference? `BuiltList` is comparable using deep equality checking, but I'm not sure `List.unmodifiable` will do the same